# Scala cast Any to Option[T]

Tags: scala, casting

Something like:

```
  def cast[T](o: Any): Option[T] = o match {
    case v: T => Some(v)
    case _ => None
  }
```

or:

```
  def cast[T](c: Class[T], o: Any): Option[T] = o match {
    case v: T => Some(v)
    case _ => None
  }
```

Is this a good idea? Is there a standard library equivalent?

Why do I get and how do I resolve the following Scala compiler warning:

```
Warning:(7, 13) abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    case v: T => Some(v)
```

Comment: You don't need a special method: `scala.util.Try(o.asInstanceOf[T]).toOption`

Comment: @Yawar that is the most succinct and relies on strictly the standard library, but it involves using exceptions as flow control. It works, but I'll take pamu's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use class tag. Type information gets lost during runtime.So, you need provide type information which can be done using class tag.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def cast[T: ClassTag](o: Any): Option[T] = o match {
 case v: T => Some(v)
 case _ => None
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> cast[String]("hello")
res2: Option[String] = Some(hello)

scala> cast[Int]("scala")
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Now, try `cast[List[String]](List[Int](1, 2, 3))`.